# Oracle Entity Framework - Foreign Key Error

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, foreign-keys

We are working with an Oracle 11g database schema (cannot be change) that defines tables and relationships as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MySchema.Parent ( 
  Parent_ID NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL, --Pk
  ... ) :

CREATE TABLE MySchema.Child (
  Child_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  Parent_ID NUMBER NOT NULL, --Fk
  ... ) :

ALTER TABLE MySchema.Child
  ADD CONSTRAINT FamilyRelation FOREIGN KEY ( Parent_ID )
    REFERENCES MICASE.PERSON ( Parent_ID );
```

Notice: In the Oracle database, the Parent table's Parent_ID is defined as `NUMBER(15,0)` and the Child table's Parent_ID is defined as `NUMBER`.

Issue: When the tables are added to .Net Entity Framework model, the IDs are "mapped to" `Int64` and `Decimal` respectively, which are not considered a match by the EF Model, which reports the following:

Error 112: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'Parent_ID' on entity 'MySchema.Child' does not match the type of property 'Parent_ID' on entity 'MySchema.Parent' in the referential constraint 'FamilyRelation'.

Please advise with solutions or workarounds to the issue.

Thanks

Notes: 
Our team does not "own" or have any option to change the Oracle data model.
I know there are a few other similar SO questions, but they are mostly older and unanswered.

Comment: `When the tables are added to .Net Entity Framework model` : how is it done ? Some tools ? Devart for example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your CSDL schema in order to match the data type required. Try change "Decimal" value to "Int64". Hope it works :)